# Save user-uploaded files from Maven Clean

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, file-upload, directory

This WebApp is developed using Maven with Java on a Tomcat server.

Once a user uploads an image it is saved under *Project/**target**/ProjectWithVersion/images* 
(this path is built by using **getServlet().getServletContext().getRealPath("/images");**)

This works, but each time the project is *cleaned* Maven deletes the **target** folder, with all the user uploaded images inside.

How can this be avoided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not run your application in the `target` folder created by Maven. Usually you want to create a WAR file and deploy it into your Tomcat which runs somewhere else.